# What does VDO sensor means?

Tags: sensor

I found some sensors in online shops titled VDO sensors ([Click on this link to check an example](https://baishanpower.en.made-in-china.com/product/NCRxDaMcZbkI/China-Vdo-Speed-Sensor-Oil-Pressure-Sensor-Temperature-Sensor-for-Engine-Deutz-Yanmar-Kubota-Denyo-Ricardo-Weifang-Yuchai-Shangchai-Engine-622-152-622-153.html)). I checked on google but nothing much came related to VDO. Can anyone kindly explain the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VDO is an established German maker of a vast range of automotive sensors, gauges, dashboards, etc., found in a variety of German - brand vehicles. In this particular case the offered product could be a licensed product, emulating VDO brand original. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDO_(company)

Answer (score 1):

[VDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDO_(company)) is/was a German manufacturer of automotive electronics. Logo from Wiki. You'll find their stuff in older BWMs etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

VDO is a German manufacturer of gauges and sensors often used in automotive and marine engine systems.  Presumably, the sensors you are referring to are intended to be used with VDO gauges, or can be used to replace "official" VDO sensors.